# change my task runner from gulp to grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, gulp, yo

I am using yeoman to scaffold my angular js application, and wasn't interested in picking a specific task runner (gulp, or grunt), hence I selected the default which was (gulp), after discussing with team we decided to use grunt.

so is it possible to change the task runner of the project from gulp to grunt using yeoman, if not, can it be done manually or I will mess up the project with lots of manual changes?

I know that I can easily create a new project and copy the source code we had written but I'd like to know if any other better way to do so.

Thanks

Comment: there are many gulp and grunt generators for angularjs. Which one do you use?

Comment: I didn't specify grunt or gulp generators when generating the application the first time, I just installed 'npm install -g generator-angular'

Comment: is there something unclear @Poyraz?

Comment: generator angular uses grunt... My intention was if you are using any structure or task runner on your current work. If there is then you should check for generators which is best fit with your project but other then this I moved from grunt to gulp and my favorite generator is https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular which is modular and follow latest and best proctices for angularjs...

Comment: Thanks Poyraz for you comment :), the concern me and my team afraid of is that gulp is relatively new with respect to grunt hence less community support, what do you think?

Comment: It was new once but now you can almost find replicas of any famous grunt task besides that coding of gulp is much more easy if you compare with grunt so you can easyly create your custom tasks without problem... I believe gulp-angular-generator will probably cover everything you need just create a sample project with it and just look tasks besides they have really good documents...